# How to keep a session alive after logging in (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, shopping-cart, cart

We are building a webshop based on Codeigniter. Products are saved in a shopping cart with help of Codeigniters' Cart Class.

When a visitor logs in with it's account, all products which are already in their cart are removed because a new session started when the user logged in.

How can we keep the products in the cart at this point?

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $user = $query->row_array();
        $data = array(
                'userid' => $user['id'],
                'email' => $user['email'],
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know exactly, but you can save in temp table and save it with user_id...

Comment: It's weird, Adding custom session data does not remove old session. could you show the logic is relevant to login process?

Comment: It's difficult to save it with a user_id because saving needs to happen before the user logs in.

Comment: @MarkdeVries Make sure `$config['sess_use_database']` is set to `TRUE`. This will [save all session data to your database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). CI Session class stores data in a cookie. So, depends on your browser settings, the data may be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new table in base, like shoppingcarts, and pass all items from that Chart class in that table, and user ID, then when user log in just query that table with his ID and ID of row now you got all products.But when user bye just delete that rows in base and unset cart class

```
  $data = array(
                   'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => 39.95,
                   'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
                   'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red'
                   'user_id  => '45')
                );

    $this->cart->insert($data);
    $chart = $this->cart->contents();
    $this->db->insert('shoppingcarts',$chart);
```

This is just simple example, how to do that :)

Comment: I understand the principle of saving the cart items in the database. But still think that I didn't clarified the situation correct. The problem is, that the cart is emptied while the visitor is on the website: visitor comes on website (not logged in), puts some products in the cart (we don't know who the user is), then decides to login (now we know which user it is), and at this point the cart gets cleared. How do I know which cart items belong to this user?

Comment: Dont allow user to add to chart, until he is loged in.

Answer (score 1):

If users have account, you need to save data in DB.

If users don't have an account and you want to keep his chart (based on browser), then you don't need to destroy session when user close the window. You need to keep it on session until he clear his chart. You can do it on `config.php` file.